# HttpClient and ProgressListener - help to implement

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload

I am just studying so I need your advice. I have found a code example which demos HttpClient progress listener. It is good but I have no idea how to implement ProgressListener interface (watch this code...) with my code because ProgressListener interface is an inner interface but my HttpClient code is in another class :( Please advise me the example tips. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

public class CountingMultipartEntity extends MultipartEntity {

private final ProgressListener listener;

public CountingMultipartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
}

public CountingMultipartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode, final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode);
    this.listener = listener;
}

public CountingMultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
        final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode, boundary, charset);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
    super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
}

public static interface ProgressListener {
    void transferred(long num);
}

public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private long transferred;

    public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(out);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.transferred = 0;
    }


    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        this.transferred += len;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        this.transferred++;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }
}
```

}

Much appreciated any useful information.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply say

```
class MyProgressListener implements CountingMultipartEntity.ProgressListener {
    public void transferred(long num) {
        System.out.println(num + " bytes transferred so far..."); //Display Progress
    }
}
```

and then

```
new CountingMultipartEntity(new MyProgressListener());
```

(edited to provide *even more* detail and fix stupid mistake)

Comment: Thank you but I don't get it ... Why you want to say with this snippet HttpClient.ProgressListener? Because the demo class name is CountingMultipartEntity, isn't it? What HttpClient.(...) is for?

Comment: How to make the MultiPartEntity interaction?

Comment: So you mean the class which contains the inner interface should be called HttpClient?

Comment: But it is called CountingMultipartEntity. Or there is something deeper?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm sorry, I've been propagating the same silly mistake through this whole interaction. No, it's CountingMultipartEntity.ProgressListener. My bad.

Comment: Oh, You scared me really :) Ok now is more clear, thanks. So you suggest to use inner class. But what about a common outer class as public class MyProgressListener ? Is it good coding style or there is a logic limit? As for this case...

Comment: It doesn't matter -- MyProgressListener can be either an inner or outer class. The one I show doesn't need access to any outer class variables, so it's a fine top-level class. But if your program had a GUI, and the ProgressListener needed to work with some member variables in the GUI -- a Swing ProgressReporter component, say -- then it would be a fine inner class, as well.

Comment: Yes, I am writing a small GUI (a frame+panel) with JProgressBar so I just wanted to show the % progress as for a HttpClient test to study the lib :) I just thought is the 2Gb an absolute max as to upload? I didn't find any tips concerning the outputstreaming limits? I just wonder...